# How do I add Google Account authentication to Google Cloud Endpoints in Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to make a Google Cloud Endpoints backend for my Android app that uses a user's Google Account for authentication.  I've found that the Java API contains annotations for OAuth scopes, but the python documentation only makes a single reference to that.

Here is the annotation I'm using on the endpoint:

```
@endpoints.api(name='notes', version='v1',
           description='Notes API',
           allowed_client_ids=[CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
           audiences=[AUDIENCE],
           scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'])
```

But the generated code doesn't have any scopes:

```
/**
 * Available OAuth 2.0 scopes for use with the .
 *
 * @since 1.4
 */
public class NotesScopes {

  private NotesScopes() {
  }
}
```

Even the generated service class seems to be missing pieces:

```
/**
 * The default encoded root URL of the service. This is determined when the library is generated
 * and normally should not be changed.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://None/_ah/api/";

/**
 * The default encoded service path of the service. This is determined when the library is
 * generated and normally should not be changed.
 *
 * @since 1.7
 */
public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "notes/v1/";
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing some annotation or config option.  Does anyone know what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scopes` attribute in the annotation isn't used in the Android auth flow, which is one of the reasons it's not included in the generated Java code. Instead, Android uses an ID token, which contains sufficient information to represent your user/application to the backend, without requesting a scope.

Comment: RE: "Even the generated service class seems to be missing pieces:", see the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients, the `None` shows up in `DEFAULT_ROOT_URL` because no `hostname` was specified before `endpointscfg.py` was run.

Comment: What's missing here, and I think is really unclear in the docs, is that you have to use a Web Client for the Audience, not an Android client.  This seems particularly counter-intuitive but some clearer docs would help. There are many other issues just like this on the web and it took a couple of weeks to piece together a solution.

Perhaps adding a section to the docs that talks about exactly what you have to do in the apis console, not just for the android stuff, but the initial part would help.